# Nodejs - MySQL Error Handling

Tags: mysql, node.js, error-handling

I would love some input on handling errors with the node-mysql library.  I am currently doing the following and it isn't anywhere close to bulletproof...

```
    exports.checkResults = function (error, result) {
    var count = 0;
    if (!error && result !== undefined) count = Object.keys(result).length;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
exports.checkResults = function (error, result) {
    var count = 0;
    if (error) {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
      return;  
    }

    if (!error && result !== undefined) count = Object.keys(result).length;
    if(!result.affectedRows) {
        return count;
    } else {
        return result.affectedRows;
    }
}
```